# Toggle span elements in div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still relatively new to jQuery and am trying to hide the text I have contained in a few spans within a div on a hover, then show them again on a hover out.  I feel like it it something relatively easy to do, I just havent had much success.  Thank you!

```
$(".resultBox").hover(function() {

    // Perform actions only if targeted result box it is not enlarged
    if($(this).height() === RESULTBOX_DEF_HEIGHT && $(this).width() === RESULTBOX_DEF_WIDTH)
    {
        // Toggle the highlight class matching the target box
        var targetBoxId = $(this)[0].id;
        $(this).toggleClass(targetBoxId + "BoxHighlight");

        // Hide all text in the spans within this box
    }
});
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML, too?

Comment: I am adding spans programmatically as I need them displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: `$(this).children().toggle();`

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to modify following to work in your favor ..

```
$("resultBox").hover(function(){
    $('.target').show();
},function(){
    $('.target').hide();
});
```